# SQL generating multiple count columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have developed some SQL to generate statistics on our local tickets database table (SQL Server 2008).  As you can see from my code, I want to select from TICKETS, joining group to get the group name, grouping by group code as well as year/month.

I want to create totals (counts) for how many tickets were open, closed, closed outside of sla (past due date), and ultimately the SLA%.

This code works, however I'm not happy with having to code all the nested (select counts); this seems like not a good strategy with multiple re-scans.

Is there a better design for generating multiple "counts" columns from a single select on a table ... or would this be the standard approach?

```
select  g.group_name as [Group],
        year(tm.date_open) as Year,
        month(tm.date_open) as Month,
        COUNT(*) as [Tickets Opened],

        (select COUNT(*)
         from TICKETS tm2
         where tm2.group_code = tm.group_code
         and year(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = year(tm.date_open)
         and month(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = month(tm.date_open)
        ) as [Tickets Closed],

        (select COUNT(*)
         from TICKETS tm2
         where tm2.group_code = tm.group_code
         and year(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = year(tm.date_open)
         and month(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = month(tm.date_open)
         and tm2.[COMPLETION_DATE] <= tm2.[DUE_DATE:]
        ) as [Closed Within SLA],   

        (select COUNT(*)
         from TICKETS tm2
         where tm2.group_code = tm.group_code
         and year(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = year(tm.date_open)
         and month(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = month(tm.date_open)
         and tm2.[COMPLETION_DATE] > tm2.[DUE_DATE:]
        ) as [Closed Outside SLA]   --service level agreement


from TICKETS tm
left join GROUPS g on g.group_code = tm.group_code
where g.group_code in ('techs', 'reps', 'phone')

and year(tm.date_open) = 2015
--and month(tm.date_open) = 3 -- specific month

group by tm.group_code, g.group_name, year(tm.date_open), month(tm.date_open)

order by g.group_name, year(tm.date_open), month(tm.date_open)
```

I am also going to want to add a SLA% column which will be ([Closed Within SLA] / [Tickets Closed]) * 100.  But as I see it from my current design, I would have to add redundant nested SELECTS for another column, such as ...

```
(
    cast((select COUNT(*)
     from TICKETS tm2
     where tm2.group_code = tm.group_code
     and year(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = year(tm.date_open)
     and month(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = month(tm.date_open)
     and tm2.[COMPLETION_DATE] <= tm2.[DUE_DATE:]
    ) as decimal) /
    (select COUNT(*)
     from TICKETS tm2
     where tm2.group_code = tm.group_code
     and year(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = year(tm.date_open)
     and month(tm2.COMPLETION_DATE) = month(tm.date_open)
    )
) * 100 as [SLA%]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do much better than a bunch of subqueries.  In a single aggregate query, you can get separate counts of rows that satisfy different conditions by computing the `SUM()` of various expressions that evaluate to 1 when the condition is satisfied and zero otherwise.  Alternatively, you can `COUNT()` expressions that evaluate to non-`NULL` for exactly those rows you wish to count.  For example, it looks like this may be close to what you're after:

```
SELECT
  g.group_name AS [Group],
  year(tm.date_open) as Year,
  month(tm.date_open) as Month,
  COUNT(*) AS [Tickets Opened],
  COUNT(tm.completion_date) AS [Tickets Closed],
  SUM(CASE WHEN tm.completion_date <= [DUE_DATE:] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    AS [Closed Within SLA],
  SUM(CASE WHEN tm.completion_date > [DUE_DATE:] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    AS [Closed Outside SLA],   --service level agreement
  CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN tm.completion_date <= [DUE_DATE:] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    AS decimal) / COUNT(tm.completion_date)) AS [SLA%],
FROM
  tickets tm
  LEFT JOIN GROUPS g
    ON g.group_code = tm.group_code
WHERE
  g.group_code in ('techs', 'reps', 'phone')
  and year(tm.date_open) = 2015
  -- and month(tm.date_open) = 3 -- specific month
GROUP BY
    tm.group_code,
    g.group_name,
    year(tm.date_open),
    month(tm.date_open)
ORDER BY
    g.group_name,
    year(tm.date_open),
    month(tm.date_open)
```

Comment: This is great, John.  I modified my query per your example and it works great. The strategy is good for me to learn; thanks for that. Also to note, the speed increase is HUGE.  My nested select statement was running about 30 seconds.  After modifying to your approach, I thought something was wrong because when I ran it the response was nearly immediate, less than a second! Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure of the protocol here on Stackoverflow ... so while the answer is a great example how to rework my issue, and I thought it perfect, upon closer analysis, the result is actually not accurate for my case.  At issue is in my scenario, a ticket could be opened at end of one month and closed in next month. My original design would accurately include those in the [tickets closed] count, whereas with John's approach, those counts are missed because the open and close months would be diferent.  And I don't see how to account for that is this design?

Comment: @Riccarr, if I have adequately answered *the question that you posed*, then you should consider my answer a candidate for acceptance.  You may, of course, discuss the answer further in comments, as you are doing.  With respect to the behavior difference you observed, you can use the technique I presented to alter the condition for tickets to be counted as closed.  I observe, however, that I think you have it backward: the query I presented will count *all* tickets in each group that have non-`NULL` completion date "closed"; it is the original that counts only those completed in the same month.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it adequately answers my original question on how to "generate multiple "counts" columns from a single select". Thanks.